# Restar el iva a un importe total

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy intentando restar $Total - $iva

se podría hacer así o hay otra manera de hacerlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`"$importe_iva-$total_compras_filtro Total sin Iva"`

Comment: Cuando compartas código, por favor, hacelo en formato texto. No se puede copiar y pegar de las imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacerlo así:

```php
    // ... Código anterior
    ."{$importe_iva - $total_compras_filtro} Total sin Iva"
```

Más info: [Cadenas > Sintaxis compleja (llaves)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

---

Otra opción sería hacer la resta y contactenar el resultado:

```php
    // ... Código anterior
    . ($importe_iva - $total_compras_filtro) . " Total sin Iva"
```

Comment: ok. Gracias lo pruebo y os digo